# how can i securely access firebase data to auto populate a web page?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When the user goes to the events page I would like the JS to automatically retrieve the data from FIREBASE and populate the HTML (WITHOUT the user having to log in). I used the "signInAnonymously" function in the code I posted. It seems to work but how do I automatically log out as well???  Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  I've tried using firebase.auth().signOut() in various places to no avail.

```
    (function () {
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();

  let database = firebase.database();
  let ref = database.ref('events');

  // Query DB - init UI once
  ref.once('value', getDBData, DBerror);


  // Data parsing and DOM manipulation code follows here but no issues with that part........



}());
```

Comment: there can be different approaches. It depends when you want to sign out. If you want to sign out on tab close one idea can be using session storage. after successful sign in store your token in browsers session storage and whenever the user will restart his browser and there is no token available in session storage  you can sign in again

Comment: Why is it important to automatically sign out?  Typically users sign out when they choose to.

Comment: "I've tried using firebase.auth().signOut() in various places to no avail." Where did you put this code? What didn't work when you used this code?

Comment: I created a simple cms for my friend to update his own events on his webpage. This works as wanted... he signs in, updates information, logs out. All is well. The events page of his website that the users see needs to retrieve the data from firebase to populate the web page.  After the page logs in to the data base it stays logged in, so someone could access the DB as well

Comment: To Frank - I've tried to limit the amount of code i posted because most of it was not related to DB access.  I initially assumed placing firebase.auth().signOut() at the end would mean that would be the last of the code to run